# SFTP file locking semantics

Tags: locking, sftp, race-condition, blocking

I'm working with a client who synchronises certain kinds of information with us via SFTP. This isn't ideal, but it's what we have for now. They drop files for us to read in one folder, we drop files for them to read in another.

I can imagine some issues with this process, but the main ones are...

1. is there any way to know if a file from another party is completely uploaded?
2. does creating, updating, fetching or any other operation on a file lock it or block any other simultaneous operations on that file until it has finished?

Comment: So SFTP (in text) or FTP (in title and tags)?

Comment: SFTP as in the text